# how to use regex on in a find function in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have the following statement:

```
if ($(this).find("option[text='My Cool Option1']").is(":selected"))
  //do something
```

basically I have a combobox with many options. I want to do something for options that start with `My Cool Option<any number>`

above code works for only one option `My Cool Option1`...but how do I make it work for say `My Cool Option2 ..3..4` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^=` operator matches text at the start of the attribute, but it won't check that the rest is a valid number as such (is that important?). In theory:

```
if ($(this).find("option[text^='My Cool Option']").is(":selected"))
```

**However!** There is no `text` attribute on `option`, so both this and your original code shouldn't work. It only does work because of how jQuery fetches attribute values (fetching the `text` property instead of the `text` attribute), which is trying to work around some different browser bugs. This will definitely break in the future (if nothing else, when Selectors-API Level 2 is implemented in browsers and jQuery uses that in preference to its own code).

You could try the jQuery-specific non-standard `contains` selector:

```
if ($(this).find('option:contains("My Cool Option")').is(":selected"))
```

but this could match that string elsewhere in the text, if that matters.

If you've got a non-multiple selectbox (ie. only one option may be selected), you can fetch the one selected option's `text()` and check it:

```
if ($(this).find('option:selected').text().match(/^My Cool Option\d+$/))
```

otherwise, you'd have to iterate the options looking for the match:

```
var cool= false;
for (var i= this.options.length; i-->0;) {
    var option= this.options[i];
    if (option.selected && option.text.match(/^My Cool Option\d+$/)) {
        cool= true;
    }
}
if (cool) ...
```

(It's normally best to be checking option values rather than text strings though.)

Comment: I had tried the first option you gave. that does not work. And the combo box is multiple option

Comment: Shouldn't `'^My Cool Option\d+'` be `'^My Cool Option\\d+'` ... or `/^My Cool Option\d+/`?

Comment: Yes, it should! Thanks for the catch. +added more options

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins which extend the regex capabilities of JQuery such as [this one from James Padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/).

Keep in mind that this method can be slow so use with caution and only on limited element sets.